# SQL Server 2008 find time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the accesstime between two times.

Example

```
accesstime    starttime   endtime
23:00         22:00       00:00:00
```

My query look like this

```
select accesstime 
from myTable 
where accesstime  between '22:00:00'and '00:00:00'
```

When I run the query I get no results

Why?

Comment: columns would be accesstime type datetime, starttime type datetime and endtime type datetime

Comment: Well, you are specifying what looks like time literals, not datetime literals. So `'00:00:00'` will be the start of the day and `'22:00:00'` will be 22 hours later. How about you step back one level and tell us what you're trying to achieve so we can help you at that level.

Comment: second scenario,I have a work shift starts '00:00:00' i need to display the access time  3 hours before and 3 hours after start of shift.

Comment: Sorry, you're not making too much sense at this point. Can you please edit your question and clearly explain the problem you're trying to solve? I'm good at some things (programming), but no so good at others (telepathy), so you'll have to spell it all out for me. If you do that, I might event up-vote your question and that would double your reputation.

Comment: I appreciate all the inputs, i think i found a solution to the problem, adding to what M.javad below, for my second scenario. i did following.                                                                               select * from mytable
Where convert(datetime,accesstime) BETWEEN convert(datetime,'22:00:00')
AND dateadd(day,1,convert(datetime,'00:00:00'))
union
select * from mytable
Where convert(datetime,accesstime) BETWEEN convert(datetime,'00:00:00')
AND convert(datetime,'03:00:00')

Answer (score 1):

Because the time goes from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`

so, `22:00` is bigger than `00:00:00` in the same day

edit: This considering as a `DateTime`. If they are `Varchar`, you have the same problem, because `22:00` as a `Varchar` is bigger than `00:00:00`

Comment: is there another way to display this accesstime?

Comment: Your endTime should be `'23:59:59'`, because `'00:00:00'` is the next day. `select accesstime from myTable 
where accesstime  between '22:00:00'and '23:59:59'`

Answer (score 1):

Information about [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx):

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of **test_expression** is greater than
>   or equal to the value of **begin_expression** and less than or equal to
>   the value of **end_expression**.

In your table, accesstime '23:00' (test expression) is greater than '22:00:00' (begin expression) but is **not** less than '00:00:00' (end expression) and so it returns false.

In order to see results, change your query to:

```
select accesstime from myTable 
where accesstime  between '00:00:00' and '23:00:01'
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can **Convert** times to **datetime** and by **dateadd** function add ONE day to time '00:00:00' and then it works true.

the sample code is here:

```
CREATE table EX_Time (accesstime nvarchar(100),starttime nvarchar(100),endtime nvarchar(100)) 

INSERT INTO EX_Time(accesstime,starttime,endtime)
VALUES (N'23:00:00',N'22:00:00',N'00:00:00')

select * 
FROM Ex_Time
Where convert(datetime,accesstime) BETWEEN convert(datetime,'22:00:00')
AND dateadd(day,1,convert(datetime,'00:00:00'))
```

Comment: Its rarely better to cast or convert a column as  you are forcing the clause to be non-sargable which means you are forcing a scan .More over accesstime column is a datetime type so it doesnt actually make sense to convert it again to datetime